# MenuBar open a dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying open a dialog using Primefaces 3.5. I create a `MenuBar` and an `view.xhtml` with `<p:dialog>` .I want to open this `view.xhtml` as dialog modal.

I am using: JSF2 and Primefaces 3.5

I'm trying this

```
<h:form>
        <p:menubar>
            <!-- cadastros -->
            <p:submenu label="Cadastro">
                <p:submenu label="Participantes">
                    <p:menuitem value="Aluno" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Professor"/>
                </p:submenu>
                <p:separator/>                  
                <p:menuitem value="Turma" onclick="#{menuMB.openDialog('/turma/view.xhtml')}"></p:menuitem>             
            </p:submenu>
            <!-- termina cadastros -->

            <!-- relatorios -->
            <p:submenu label="Relatorios">

            </p:submenu>    
        </p:menubar>

    </h:form>
```

view.xhtml

```
<p:dialog header="Turmas" appendToBody="false" modal="true" widgetVar="turmaView">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="I am a modal" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class MenuMB {

    public void openDialog(String view){
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("view.show()");     
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

**Solved**

view.xhtml

```
<p:dialog header="Turmas" widgetVar="turmaView"  appendToBody="true" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="I am a modal" />
    </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

menubar

```
<h:form>
            <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Cadastro">
                        <p:submenu label="Participante">
                            <p:menuitem value="Aluno"></p:menuitem>
                            <p:menuitem value="Professor"></p:menuitem> 
                        </p:submenu>    
                        <p:separator/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Turma" onclick="PF('turmaView').show()"/>                                    
                </p:submenu>            
            </p:menubar>         
    </h:form>

    <ui:include src="/turma/view.xhtml"/>
```

now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to execute server side methods wrapping them in `onclick` listeners or similars like that. You're confused about client side javascript functions and server side listeners. According to [PF docs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml):

> MenuItem has two use cases, directly navigating to a url using GET or doing a POST to execute an action.

So there's no way to use it for client-side specific purpose, as it's going to perform one request. What you could do is to show the dialog after it happens:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Turma" oncomplete="dlg.show();" />
        </p:menubar>
        <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true"
            height="100">
            <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This properly displays the dialog when the `p:menuItem` is clicked. An ajax request with no listener is performed and when it's completed, the javascript code to show it runs.

Comment: @BalusC changed the JS reference for the dialog and the namespaces ;-)

Comment: @BalusC I'm using JSF2.2 `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>` and Primefaces 3.5 also.

Comment: @BalusC dude. On my first post I did use of PF3.5 after I did update to PF4.0. I dont using PF5 like you said. Note, that I'm using dialog with `appendToBody="true"` and PF4.0 or PF5 need use `appendTo="@Body"` ...thanks a lot !

Comment: @Fernando if you change the requirement you should update your question instead. BTW, there's nothing wrong in providing your answer, but do it in the answer part and not in the question ☺